# https for single domain .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a multiple addon domains on my hosting account. I would like to redirect non-https to https for the main domain i.e

- andamanexoticholidays.com

my .htaccess approach:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but this makes all adon domain to force use ssl by default.

my addon domain are:

- radhakrishnaresorthavelock.com

and my sud domains are:

- agents.andamanexoticholidays.com

and I want to force use

- https://www.andamanexoticholidays.com

a https and www.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a RewriteCondition so that only the main domain can get redirected to https , try :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?andamanexoticholidays.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.andamanexoticholidays.com %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$ OR RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?andamanexoticholidays\.com$ ??? whichone to use

Comment: Use the first one, for which you want to force https.

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]      not working!!!